# What content does the Project Spark disc have?

Tags: xbox-one, project-spark

**My friend gave me a Project Spark Starter Pack for Xbox One.**
 
I was excited, as it is no longer available for download on the Xbox Store. Later I realized that the case he gave me didn't have a DLC code for extra content. I have reason to believe he already activated it on his account (I don't think he withheld it from me on purpose). 
    As it is August, and the community creations servers have been shut down, I no longer want the game. I learned that [one who has activated the Starter Pack DLC code will get a credit to their Microsoft Account.](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/project-spark-retirement)
That's great and all, but what about those who don't have the DLC?
**Is there some way to prove I own a retail copy of Project Spark without using the DLC?**